Is there a tool to order/pay for multiple papers at once?
I need to order/pay >100 papers that are not of open access. Is there a platform or a tool that I could use to order and pay them all at once, instead of having to do it one by one?
Thank you

I don't think such a tool exists. It would be very expensive to purchase so many papers, probably thousands of US dollars.  However, it is rarely necessary to purchase academic papers. There are often open access (ie preprint) versions of papers available for free. See Unpaywall.org for example.  Copies of many papers can also be obtained through interlibrary loans / national libraries for free/a small cost.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Maybe some big editor offer you a time-limited rental subscription ... I am not aware, but I see it possible.

Giving this type of information is what your librarian is for. So just talk to them, in all likelihood you will be walking away with not just a solution but also a cheaper solution than what you would have gotten if you tried to do it alone.

And if you are not affiliated to a university, your local university's library may still be able to help you.
